# how to use JDatePicker jar file into the program

Tags: java

I need to use 'JDatePicker' class for a program. I downloaded 'jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar' file. and when i extracted the file using the command "jar xf jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar", I got 3 folders in the directory " META-INF, tutorial, net". But i don't know how to import this to the java program and where to store this jar file and the extracted folders. could any one assist me on the above?

I don't use any IDE. I run the java programs in command prompt

Comment: You only have to add this jar to your classpath and than you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You must have that exact **jar** file on the class path. When compiling specify jar in the compile

```
javac -classpath jars\jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar -sourcepath src\project -d classes src\project\MyProg.java
```